# Android app crashes with exception.class.missing._Unknown_

Tags: android, exception, pattern-matching, google-play-console, production

I’ve just released the latest version of my app but I'm seeing this crash in the Google Play Console for some users.

```
exception.class.missing._Unknown_: 
  at com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.compileImpl (Native Method)
  at com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.<init> (PatternNative.java:39)
  at com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.create (PatternNative.java:35)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile (Pattern.java:1426)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init> (Pattern.java:1401)
  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile (Pattern.java:959)
  at com.mymedia.android.tracker.custom.MyInputFilter.<init> (MyInputFilter.java:30)
```

Is this saying that it can't find the native class / method **com.android.icu.util.regex.PatternNative.compileImpl()**? Or is it my class **MyInputFilter**?

A couple of things that I've done differently for this new release which I'm wondering could have caused this.

1. I've released an App Bundle instead of an APK.
2. I've added these Proguard / shrinking & obfusication settings in build.gradle.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

I've looked in the Proguard build output file **usage.txt** but I don't see any mention of **PatternNative** being removed or anything that might cause this.

Comment: Can you share the regex pattern you used in MyInputFilter.java:30?

Comment: Sure, the regex pattern is: Pattern.compile(String.format(locale, "[0-9]{0,%d}([\\.,][0-9]{0,%d})?", digitsBeforeDecimal, digitsAfterDecimal));

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably obfuscation of your regex in the `MyInputFilter.java:30`. Try prevent obfuscation on your class fields by adding these lines to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.mymedia.android.tracker.custom.MyInputFilter {
    *;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - what you've suggested definitely is worth trying. I can't recreate the crash myself so will have to release a new production version and hope that this solves it.

Comment: Let me if it works for you or not. You can also try to deobfuscate your APK with and without this rule and try to find out what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply mistakenly set all activities in my app with the property
`android:exported` with the value `false`. But we should set at least one of them, usually the main Activity to use:

```
android:exported=true
```

This will simply allow the OS to start the main activity of your app.

I hope it helps.